# Converting ECQL from geotools to SQL

Tags: java, geoserver, geotools

Is there a java library for converting ECQL(geotools) to SQL ?

CQL and ECQL
CQL (Common Query Language) is a query language created by the OGC for the Catalogue Web Services specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GeoTools can convert most (many?) `filter` objects to SQL before sending them to a `JDBCDatastore` but it usually depends on which database you are targetting. See, for example, `org.geotools.data.postgis.PostgisFilterToSQL` - you could do something like:

```
Filter filter = EQCL.toFilter("My filter goes here");
FilterToSQL encoder = new PostgisFilterToSQL(new PostGISDialect(null));
encoder.setInline(true); // don't adding WHERE
String sql = encoder.encodeToString(filter);
```